# Criar um filtro a partir de um valor de um campo

Tags: javascript

Bom dia

Criei dois campos para seleção. E um deles possui uma lista de valores.
Quando selecionado o valor, em outro campo, que também terá uma lista, preciso que apareça somente os valores correspondentes.

No exemplo abaixo, o código no lado relaciona a descrição do lado direito.
Dessa forma quando seleciono o código 411075145 quero que no outro campo de selecão pareça as descrições Acordo, Depósito e Guia INSS

> 411075145 - Acordo
>
> 411075145 - Depósito
>
> 411075145 - Guia INSS

Abaixo o segue o código:

```
function  CarregarRelativo() {
    $('#Relativo').empty();
    AddDropDownItem('Relativo', '', '');
    
    var 
    var data = GetListItems('02FC4BE9-B056-486D-A9C6-3743DF5F9257',"?$orderby=Title");
    
    if (data != null) {
        data.forEach(function(item) {
            AddDropDownItem('Relativo', item.DescricaoContaContabil,item.DescricaoContaContabil);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Tá um pouco confusa sua pergunta, você tem um checkbox com código e outro com outro com de acordo o código selecionado, não entendi. Poderia explicar melhor ?

Comment: Desculpa, vamos la. tenho dois checkbox , no checkbox1 esta os códigos e 
 no checkbox2 deverá listar os textos de acordo com o código selecionado no checkbox1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela seu código não dá para ajudar pois não sei o que você está fazendo em AddDropDownItem.

Mas segue um exemplo que obtém o código de um  e adiciona a descrição em outro.

Veja se serve.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ListCodigosDescricao = [];
    ListCodigosDescricao.push({Codigo: 12345151, Descricao:'Formulario 1'});
    ListCodigosDescricao.push({Codigo: 84574848, Descricao:'Formulario 2'});
    ListCodigosDescricao.push({Codigo: 45487548, Descricao:'Formulario 3'});
    
    var selectCodigos = $('#selectCodigos');
    
    $.each(ListCodigosDescricao, function(i, el){
     selectCodigos.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + el.Codigo + '</option>');
    });
    
   $("#selectCodigos").change(function(){
     var itemDaLista = ListCodigosDescricao[this.value];
        $('#selectDescricao').append('<option value="">' + itemDaLista.Descricao + '</option>');
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Selecione um Código:</label>
<select id='selectCodigos'>
  <option></option>
</select>
<br/>
<label>Selecione uma Descrição:</label>
<select id='selectDescricao'>
  <option></option>
</select>
```